# Java off heap memory and huge pages

Tags: java, jvm, huge-pages, off-heap

When allocating off-heap memory in Java (through direct buffers, or JNI native code for example), will the allocated memory be backed by huge pages if the JVM is using -XX:+UseLargePages ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, HotSpot JVM [uses](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/b0a5beaac2b3/src/hotspot/share/prims/unsafe.cpp#l360) a plain libc `malloc` call to allocate memory for a direct ByteBuffer.

However, if you replace the standard system allocator with, for example, [jemalloc](http://jemalloc.net/) - you'll be able to [configure](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/issues/1127) malloc to use huge pages when available.

Another option to use huge pages for direct ByteBuffers is to create a file on a [hugetlbfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt) filesystem and then map it in Java as a [`MappedByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html).

Comment: I guess using libhugetlbfs to overload the malloc behaviour when expanding the heap would be another option? Would this solution or the jemalloc one work for malloc calls done via JNI?

Comment: @user36568 Right, libhugetlbfs should do the job, too. It will work both for direct ByteBuffers and other malloc calls in JNI code.